# Get arrayed form results one-by-one in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm creating a web form that potentially has multiple inputs with the same form element names. I need to retrieve the results of the form and output one by one.

ie. `name="supplier[]"` and `name="listPrice[]"` may have multiple results and I need each arrays results to be returned in order:
Supplier: [0], List Price: [0]
Supplier: [1], List Price: [1]
and so on.

I have a counter that is also saved as an array to provide context for each 'grouped' result and a foreach loop is currently providing the correct output for the counter but nothing else. Probably my limited PHP/array knowledge or just having been looking at this for too long is making me completely miss the best solution.

Form structure is like this:

```
<h4>Request #` + counter + `</h4>
            <input type="hidden" name="codeId[]" class="code-id" value="` + counter + `">

<select class="custom-select supplier-select" name="supplier[]" id="supplier` + counter +`">
    <option selected value>Default</option>
    <option value="One">Supplier One</option>
    <option value="Two">Supplier Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Supplier Three</option>
</select>

<input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control list-price" name="listPrice[]" aria-label="List Price" required>
```

jQuery grabs the result and stores in multiple arrays, then passes through to `process.php`:

```
var formValues = {
            codeId          :   $('.code-id'),
            supplier        :   $('.supplier-select'),
            listPrice       :   $('.list-price')
        };

        $.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
            var data = value.map(function() {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                formData.append(key + '[]', data[i]);
                console.log(key + " " + data);
            }
        });
```

Then my attempt to loop through each in PHP, and I have to store as a single string to pass into my mailer code:

```
if(is_array($codeId)) {

            foreach ($supplier as $key => $value) {
                $suppliers .= $value;
            }
            foreach ($listPrice as $key => $value) {
                $listPrices .= $value;
            }

            foreach ($codeId as $key => $value) {
                $string .= "Request #" . $codeId[$key] . "<br />";
                $string .= $suppliers . "<br />";
                $string .= $listPrices . "<br />";
            }

        } else {
            $string = 'Failed';
        }
```

Submitting the form as this -
Supplier: [select] One, List Price: [input] 3423
Supplier: [select] Two, List Price: [input] 466

Produces the below, I know I'm close but just not sure how best to do this!

```
Request #1
OneTwo
3423466
Request #2
OneTwo
3423466
```

What am I missing? Or how could this be handled better? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP script is doing exactly what you coded it to do. You're concatenating the results into a single string and that's what you're outputting. It sounds like what you want is each result in separate sections.

You can acheive this by using the `$key` iterator in your `foreach` loop (the third one) to select the corresponding elements in the other arrays, like so:

```
if(is_array($codeId)) {

    // get rid of the other loops

    $string = "";
    foreach ($codeId as $key => $value) {
        $string .= "Request #" . $codeId[$key] . "<br />";
        $string .= $supplier[$key] . "<br />";
        $string .= $listPrice[$key] . "<br />";
    }
}
```

This assumes that they're all the same length and that entry `i` in `listPrices` corresponds to entry `i` in the `codeId` array and `supplier` (you can check for this or enforce it if need be).

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much! This works exactly how I want it to. I knew this would be something very simple that I was missing; I was getting a bit confused about key/value pairs in array.

Comment: Cool! If this helped, consider marking this as an answer to your question (green checkmark) so that it can help others

Answer (score 0):

When combining the data to send, consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var formValues1 = {
    codeId: $('.code-id').val(),
    supplier: $('.supplier-select').val(),
    listPrice: $('.list-price').val()
  };
   var formValues2 = {
    "codeId[]": $('.code-id').val(),
    "supplier[]": $('.supplier-select').val(),
    "listPrice[]": $('.list-price').val()
  };

  var formData = new FormData();

  $.each(formValues1, function(key, value) {
    formData.append(key + '[]', value);
    console.log(key + ": " + value);
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(formValues2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Request #1</h4>
<input type="hidden" name="codeId[]" class="code-id" value="1">

<select class="custom-select supplier-select" name="supplier[]" id="supplier-1">
  <option selected value>Default</option>
  <option value="One">Supplier One</option>
  <option value="Two">Supplier Two</option>
  <option value="Three">Supplier Three</option>
</select>

<input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control list-price" name="listPrice[]" aria-label="List Price" required>
```

You may also want to use `.each()` to iterate a group selection.

Hope that helps.